# which uages of Would

Tags: grammar

I know that *would* has different usages, for requests, conditionals, Habitual actions in the past, Talking about the future in the past, Willingness in the past, Being less direct....

which usages of 'would' is used in the sentence below for the two bold 'would'?

> our volition isn't the focus of our hope in that scenario. Compare:
>   (7a) I hope they award us the prize.
>   (7b) I hope they will award us the prize.
>   Supposing we had won, we probably **wouldn't** use (7a), for their awarding us the prize **would** be expected..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both uses of "would" in bold can be classed as conditionals.

"Supposing we had won" is another way of saying "If we had won".  So the sentence can be understood as combining two conditional sentences ("if we had won, we probably wouldn't use (7a)", and "If we had won, their awarding us the prize would be expected").